# "Hello world" exercise in c++ throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: c++, arrays, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

My textbook showed this piece of C++ code to run however when I run it on net beans it displays this error **Exception in thread "main" ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{ 
  cout << "Hello world";
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), the documentation of your C++ compiler, perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to be invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then read the documentation of your debugger, perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). You could be interested in installing [Debian](https://debian.org/) and [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

there is no  ***java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*** in c++

that error is because netbeans is running another java project instead.

rightclick on the c++ project and click on "close others..."
then you can work on the right one.